# Displaying all users in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a template that I am trying to display all users in called userList.

//server

```
Meteor.publish("userList", function() {

var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
    _id: this.userId
});


if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ["admin"])) {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
            profile_name: 1,
            emails: 1,
            roles: 1
        }
    });
}

this.stop();
return;
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can pass ```this.userId``` instead of ```user``` for example ```if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'])) {..}```

Answer (score 16):

if you want show all the user you can try  in your publish.js file:

```
Meteor.publish('userList', function (){ 
  return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

in your router you susbcribe to this

```
Router.route('/users', {
    name: 'usersTemplate',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('userList');
    },
    data: function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({});       
    }
 });
```

The next step is iterate your data in the template.

if you don't want subscribe in the router, you can subscribe in template level, please read this article for more details.

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Regards.

Comment: How do you iterate the data in the template?

Answer (score 7):

This should work!

// in server

```
    Meteor.publish("userList", function () {
           return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
    });
```

// in client

```
    Meteor.subscribe("userList");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm not able to iterate through these in my template. Do you know how that would look?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

1. subscribe(client)
2. publish(server)

Client:

```
UserListCtrl = RouterController.extend({
    template: 'UserList',
    subscriptions: function () {
       return Meteor.subscribe('users.list', { summary: true });  
    },
    data: function () {
       return Meteor.users.find({});
    }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('users.list', function (options) {
    check(arguments, Match.Any);
    var criteria = {}, projection= {};
    if(options.summary){
       _.extend(projection, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
    }
    return Meteor.users.find(criteria, projection);
});
```